# subrow issue in SKSTableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is there anyone using SKSTableView and knows the subrow stuff ? I'm encountering the problem that in delegate method

```
func tableView(tableView: SKSTableView!, cellForSubRowAtIndexPath indexPath:     
NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {}
```

no matter how many number of subrows are returned, indexPath.subrow keeps giving me 0, which is the index of the first subrow. So the subrow cell can only fetch the first item of the given array.

Please help and thanks ahead.

Comment: indeed this is a bug from SKSTableVIew, if you set shouldExpandOnlyOneCell to true, the cellForSubRowAtIndexPath func always give you 0 for subrow. However, if you set shouldExpandOnlyOneCell to false, the block should return the correct corresponding subrow index to you.

Comment: Tried this but facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

you have to update NSIndexPath category

```
- (NSInteger)subRow
{

    id myclass = [SKSTableView class];
  //  id subRowObj = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, SubRowObjectKey);
    id subRowObj = objc_getAssociatedObject(myclass, SubRowObjectKey);
    return [subRowObj integerValue];
}

- (void)setSubRow:(NSInteger)subRow
{
    id subRowObj = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:subRow];

    id myclass = [SKSTableView class];
   // objc_setAssociatedObject(self, SubRowObjectKey, subRowObj, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    objc_setAssociatedObject(myclass, SubRowObjectKey, subRowObj, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```